# what is the probability that drawn balls have the same number?

Tags: probability

In the urn, there is one ball with number $1$, $2$ with number $2$, and so on until $n$ balls with the number $n$.

From the urn, we draw two balls.

Calculate the probability that the two drawn balls have the same number.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit the question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ denote the first chosen number and let $Y$ denote the second chosen number.

Then for $n\geq2$:

$$P(X=Y)=\sum_{k=2}^nP(X=k)P(Y=k\mid X=k)=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\frac12n(n+1)}\frac{k-1}{\frac12n(n+1)-1}=$$$$\frac8{n(n+1)[n(n+1)-2]}\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{k}2=\frac8{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+1}3=\frac{4}{3n+6}$$

Comment: Why am i getting a different answer? calculation error or logical?

Comment: @omega In your answer numerator and denominator should be switched. That is all.

Comment: that was silly, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

Total number of balls is $$\frac{(n)\cdot (n+1)}{2}$$
So, sample space is $$^{(\frac{(n)\cdot (n+1)}{2})}C_2$$
You want to  select 2 balls of similar number. This starts from ball numbered 2.
Number of ways to select 2 balls from each group of same numbered balls is
$$^2C_2+^3C_2+.....+^nC_2$$

> So, final solution is:
>   $$\frac{(^2C_2+^3C_2+.....+^nC_2)}{^{(\frac{(n)\cdot (n+1)}{2})}C_2}$$

Further simplification: $$ (^2C_2+^3C_2+.....+^nC_2)$$ 
can be written as $$\frac{1}{2} \cdot (2\cdot1+3\cdot2+4\cdot3+....+n\cdot(n-1))$$
Let $$2S=(2\cdot1+3\cdot2+4\cdot3+....+n\cdot(n-1))$$
$$2S=\Sigma_1^n  n\cdot(n-1)$$
$$2S=\frac{n\cdot(n^2-1)}{3}$$
So, $$S=\frac{n\cdot(n^2-1)}{6}$$
$$ ^\frac {n\cdot(n+1)}{2}C_2=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2})\cdot(\frac{n^2+n-1}{2})$$

> Giving you $$\frac{4}{3({n+2})} $$

Comment: And further simplification can be made by writing out the explicit expression for $^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}C_2$, which is just $\frac{(n^2+n)(n^2+n-2)}{8}$, so this gives the final answer as $\frac{3(n+2)}{4}$. This is of course incorrect. You might have overcounted something.

Comment: Something, what?

Comment: Switch numerator and denominator in order to repair.

Comment: Your numerator and denominator are reversed from the first statement of the final solution. Just switch them, and the answer agrees with @drhab .

Comment: @Trebor, edited...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Overall there are $N=1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ balls.
You need to calculate:
$$\begin{align}P(2\cap 2)+P(3\cap 3)+\cdots +P(n\cap n)=\\
\frac{2}{N}\cdot \frac1{N-1}+\frac{3}{N}\cdot \frac2{N-1}+\cdots+\frac{n}{N}\cdot \frac{n-1}{N-1}=\\
\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)=\\
\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)=\\
\frac1{N(N-1)} \left[\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk\right]=\\
\frac1{N(N-1)} \left[N\cdot \frac{2n+1}{3}-N\right]=\\
\frac{2(n-1)}{3(N-1)}=\\
\frac{4(n-1)}{3(n(n+1)-2)}=\\
\frac{4}{3(n+2)}.\\
\end{align}$$